# command not found in jenkins running on Mac machine

Tags: macos, jenkins

I predominantly work on windows OS and quite new to MAC systems. I am trying to set up Jenkins CI tool on one of the MAC machines, I have installed jenkins on mac  and it is running on 8080 port.

Issue: I am getting the following error on Jenkins console output when i execute the job:

```
**/var/folders/zz/zzzivhrRnAmviuee+++++E++++2/-Tmp-/hudson6910375920437308281.sh: line 13:
  **ampts: command not found**
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure**
```

Things I tried:

1. I added the correct path in .bash_profile and since then I am able to successfully run the ampts command from terminal and every thing works fine from terminal. But the same does not run from the execute shell in Jenkins which is running on MAC.
2. Earlier the job was running as anonymous I created the account in jenkins and placed `.bash_profile` with the correct path under `~jenkins/users/home/my.account` and restarted jenkins but still I am facing the same issue.
3. I also tried placing `.bashrc` under `~jenkins` and also under `~jenkins/users/home/my.account` but still no success.

Can some one point out what I am missing. or what needs to be done in case of Jenkins running on MAC.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the failure to build happens when using the Jenkins webpage interface? I believe that the properties are set in the launch daemon settings in /Library/LaunchDaemon (or LaunchAgent) /org.jenkins-ci.plist. Maybe you need to setup the environment variables there? See the manpage for launchctl for details.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how you've started the Jenkins client.  If you start it from the command line with the `javaws` command then I think this will inherit the environment variables of the terminal prompt.  If you start the JNLP agent from the browser then it will inherit the system environment (which is different to the bash environment).  There's a few things you could try:

- Set the PATH variable explicitly in the `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` file (see the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html))
- If you are using Ant to run the jobs then you can add the environment variable to the `~/.antrc` file (same syntax as the `.bash_profile`)
- Set the environment variable in the Jenkins configure page for this node.